# Does day length determine metabolism?

Tags: evolution

Would an organism that evolved on a world with a short day length have a faster metabolism in comparison to one that evolved on a slower rotating world?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not as if here on Earth there exists a "standard" metabolic rate. Some animals have a very high metabolic rate, others have a very low metabolic rate. By and large, warm blooded animals have higher metabolic rates than cold blooded animals, and small animals have higher metabolic rates than large animals. I don't get the reference to day length and in what way it could influence metabolic rate.

Comment: @AlexP presumably the thinking is that you'd have to hunt and eat faster to make use of the shorter day, but then you have to wait less time til dawn/dusk/your preferred snack time came again...

Comment: We can see on earth that this depends on lifestyle and food sources. Koalas are very slow, since they only eat eucalyptus. How would longer days benefit them? Cats are very active when awake, hence they sleep a lot, mostly during the day. By your logic, they would need a slower metabolism then? Pro athletes eat 5 times of what non active people should eat. Length of day - one factor in a million.

Answer (score 2):

The more active a creature is the higher its metabolic rate.

And small creatures have higher per-gram metabolic rates than larger animals.

https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/principles-of-physiology/metabolism-and-thermoregulation/a/metabolic-rate

So the day length wouldn't affect a metabolism **UNLESS**.

**If their short day lengths lead to little activity, they may have a slower metabolism. Meanwhile, longer days may cause an extremely high metabolism if creatures are incredibly active.** So it is dependent on the creature's rate of activity, but the length of day can affect their activity, which in turn may help be a factor that attributes to a different metabolism.